# ASP.NET repeater item retrieve and change property

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have the following `<asp:repeater>`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Bind("Photos") %>' OnItemCreated="Repeater1_itemCreated" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="thumbs">
            <a href='Images/Parts/Photos/<%# Eval("PhotoId") %>.jpg' 
               rel="lightbox-parts">
            <img id="smallPhotoImg" alt="" width="70px" height="70px" 
                 src='Images/Parts/Thumbs/<%# Eval("PhotoId") %>.jpg' />
            </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

It displays all images for needed "Part" but what I need is to hide the image i.e repeater item if `Photos.IsDefault == true`

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to hide just the <img>, or the entire repeater?

Is Photos.IsDefault a property of the entire data source? In that case, why not just wrap the repeater in as ASP:PlaceHolder and set it to visible=false (ie check Photos.IsDefault before you databind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have arrived at a solution:

The purpose was to hide the `img`. `Photos.isDeFault` is a database field:

This is what I came up with:

```
Photo photo = (Photo)e.Item.DataItem;
if (photo != null)
    if (photo.IsDefault)
        e.Item.Visible = false;
```